# Convert this angularjs datetime format to a shorter one

Tags: javascript, angularjs, datetime

I have a table with one of the columns showing datetime value. I am using angularjs ngtable module.

```
<div ng-controller="TestCtrl" class="container">
    <table ng-table="tableParams" class="table table-bordered">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>name</th>
            <th>date</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="test in $data">
            <td data-title="'name'" >
                {{test.name}}
            </td>
            <td data-title="'remarks'">
                {{test.date}}
            </td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

An example of `{{test.date}}` looks something like `2015-12-08T16:00:00.000Z`. I would like to convert it to `Dec08 16:00:00`. How can this be done in angularjs?

Comment: use 
`min="{{minDatetimeLocal | date:'yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss'}}"
max="{{maxDatetimeLocal | date:'yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss'}}"`

to set format of datetime you want

Answer (score 5, accepted):

yes, in Angular doc you have examples: [**Link**](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date)

try something like: `{{test.name | date:'MMMdd HH:mm:ss'}}`

Comment: Could you ellaborate your answer somemore details. If the link is expired, the answer is not useful for other.